# Get JSONArray with Volley in Android

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I'm trying to get this `JSONArray` with android but I can't get `codigo` and `nombre` of all items.

I leave the `JSON` that I'm trying to get:

> {"categorias":
>   {"cfcd208495d565ef66e7dff9f98764da":{"orden":0,"codigo":"001","nombre":"TUBO Y ACCESORIO DE COBRE, LATON"},
>   "c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b":{"orden":1,"codigo":"002","nombre":"TUBO Y ACCESORIO PVC PRESION"},
>   "c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c":{"orden":2,"codigo":"003","nombre":"AISLAMIENTO"},
>   "eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3":{"orden":3,"codigo":"004","nombre":"MONTAJE DE AGUA SANITARIA"},
>   "a87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b7542122c":{"orden":4,"codigo":"005","nombre":"ABRAZADERAS FONTANERIA"},"e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5":{"orden":5,"codigo":"006","nombre":"FLEXOS DE ACERO"},
>   "1679091c5a880faf6fb5e6087eb1b2dc":{"orden":6,"codigo":"007","nombre":"ACCESORIOS DE SANEAMIENTO"},
>       ...
>       ...
>       ...

This is my code on Android, and I always get null response:

```
 JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, showUrl, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        System.out.println("Respuesta:"+ response.toString());
                        try {
                            listaCategorias.clear();
                            int array=0;

                            JSONArray categorias = response.getJSONArray("categorias");

                            for (int i = 0; i < categorias.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject objet = categorias.getJSONObject(i);

                                String titulo = objet.getString("nombre");

                                if (isIntegerParseInt(String.valueOf(titulo.charAt(0))))
                                    listaCategorias.add(titulo);

                            }
                            array++;
                            onCallBack.onSuccess(listaCategorias);



                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println("ErrorRespuesta: "+error.getMessage());

            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: "categorias" is not a `JSONArray`. it's a `JSONObject`

Answer (score 3):

its not an JSON ARRAY 
Its JSON OBJECT
for your reference I'm posting sample json array

```
"three_day_forecast": [
    { 
        "conditions": "Partly cloudy",
        "day" : "Monday",
        "temperature": 20 
    },
    { 
        "conditions": "Showers",
        "day" : "Tuesday",
        "temperature": 22 
    },
    { 
        "conditions": "Sunny",
        "day" : "Wednesday",
        "temperature": 28 
    }
]
```

Data was used by [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper/d8bb95982be8a11a2308e779bb9a9707ebe42ede/sample_json) reference.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an Array but a JSONObject you need to modify your JSON to get an array with [] and not {}. Or you get it by getJSONObject.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to the JSON String you've posted `categorias` is not a **JSONArray**. it's an object and the JSON string is still invalid.

On the top of the String you have the key as **categories**, now if you want to use that as an array you must have the value of **categories** to array which is specified within **[ ]** in JSON strings.

Another thing is try to avoid random key of the **JSON Array** if you're using it within loops with indexes. So your **JSON String** might look like following to support your Android code.

```
{
"categories": [
     { object 1... },
     { object 2... },
     and so on...
]
}
```

You can see the type of **JSON** you will need here:
http://json-parser.com/53b37f69